# Problems with forwarding arguments to std::thread constructor

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, stdthread

I am trying to create a class Thread that aims to wrap std::thread in such a way that it doesn't immmediately start upon construction, but rather has to be started separately. This requires a template constructor, since such is the constructor of std::thread. Here is the code:

```
class Thread
        {
        public:
            template<class Function, class ... Args>
            Thread(Function&& function, Args&& ... args)
                :myThread(&Thread::wrapper<Function, Args...>, std::forward<Function>(function), std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            {
                started.lock();
            }
            void start()
            {
                started.unlock();
            }

        private:
            std::thread myThread;
            std::mutex started;

            template<class Function, class ... Args>
            static void wrapper(Function&& function, Thread& thread, Args&& ... args)
            {
                // Wait until it is started
                thread.started.lock();

                // Execute the function
                function(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
            }
        };
```

And this line seems to be the problem:
`:myThread(&Thread::wrapper<Function&&, Args&&...>, std::forward<Function>(function), std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong in this instance, since the code won't compile, and there are only 3 (for me) cryptic errors.

Error   C2672   'invoke': no matching overloaded function found

Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Ty1 &&,_Types2 &&...) noexcept()'

Error   C2780   'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept()': expects 1 arguments - 4 provided

If anyone could help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The posted code compiles well. Please be kind to post a [mcve].

Comment: You likely want `&Thread::wrapper<Function, Args...>`, without ampersands.

Comment: You seem to be hoping that `started.lock();` in `Thread` constructor would execute before `thread.started.lock();` in `wrapper` - but nothing in the code guarantees that. You may or may not get lucky. It's possible that the two are called in the "right" order with a higher probability, so it seems to work, giving you are false sense of security. But really, you are just throwing a (possibly loaded) dice.

Comment: Hey, nice catch, even though it doesn't change my compilation problem. You probably saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
:myThread(&Thread::wrapper<Function&&, Args&&...>, std::forward<Function>(function), std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

by

```
:myThread(&Thread::wrapper<Function, Args...>, std::forward<Function>(function), std::ref(*this), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

&& are for universal references, not r-values in your case

Comment: You are right actually, but it still doesn't work. Thank you still.

Comment: what "does not work"?

Comment: Fails to compile, with the same errors